# Insert products into wordpress without being a virtual store?

Tags: wordpress

I need to create an institutional site with many items that our company, but I will not sell them on the internet, I just want customers to access our site and search there by category and type of products, and each product would like to insert a video and some Images so that I can disclose them, I already tried to use woocommerce but as it has checkout and cart I was not able to use it. The way is this to use the same woocommerce, or is there any plugin for this purpose? In the portfolio I registered the type of services we do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a custom type post for 'products' and it will show up like a 'Post' with categories if you want to.

Here is one I usually use:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/